# How to get the first two numbers in an integral?

Tags: php, javascript

How to get the first two numbers in an integral?

For example: get 12 of the 123456 in PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**PHP:**

```
$num = 123456;
echo substr($num, 0, 2);
```

**JavaScript:**

```
alert((123456).toString().substr(0, 2));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for large numbers, though. 1234500000000000000000 becomes '.1' instead of '12'.

Comment: if you wrap it in qoutes eg `'1234500000000000000000'`, it sould work and then you can type cast later once you have got the desired part of the number. Example: `$num = '1234500000000000000000';
$output =  substr($num, 0, 2);
echo (int) $output;
`

Comment: @Guffa: Ofcourse not but as i said once you get the required digits, you can type cast them again to convert them to number. And as Delan Azabani said, that is because it converts to scientific notation. Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz: You are missing the point. If the input is a variable containing a numeric value, you can't just put apostrophes around it. If you could change the input that way, you could just as easily remove all but the first two characters, and this entire question would be pointless.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript:

```
(123456).toString().substr(0,2);
```

PHP:

```
substr(123456, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Really? I was just typoecasting to make sure. I'll simplify it, thanks very much! ;)

Comment: Doesn't work for large numbers, though. 1234500000000000000000 becomes '.1' instead of '12'.

Comment: @Guffa: That's because calling `.toString()` on large numbers gives the scientific notation (X.Ye+Z)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, perhaps I should have included the reason in my comment but it seemed so obvious at the time...

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = substr("123456", 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Numerically in Javascript:

```
while (number >= 100) number = Math.floor(number / 10);
```

Comment: @Alsciende: Yes, you are right. I changed it to remove the fractions.